# access db object in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In meteor, if you start `meteor mongo`, you get a shell, where you can access the database purely as mongo.

```
project :: (master*) » meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
Mongo-Hacker 0.0.4
meteor:PRIMARY> db.users.find().count()
6
meteor:PRIMARY>
```

I want to access the item that is like the `db`, but with Meteor. For a simple example,

```
function getTableEntityCount(tablename) {
  return db[tablename].find().count();
}
```

Is this possible in Meteor?

Answer (score 4):

You can try with the mongodb native driver.

```
    // Server code
    //Typical require 
    var mongodb = Meteor.npmRequire("mongodb"), //using arounfa meteorhacks:npm
        db = mongodb.Db,
        mongoclient = mongodb.MongoClient,
        Server = mongodb.Server,
        db_connection = new Db('cats', new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017 {auto_reconnect: false}));

db.open(function(err, db) { 
    db.authenticate('<username>', '<password>', function(err, result) {
        //return db[tablename].find().count();
     });
});
```

This is just conceptual code.

Comment: Meteor 1.0.4 also introduced some new raw DB access points: https://www.meteor.com/blog/2015/03/17/meteor-104-mongo-cordova-template-subscriptions

Comment: huh, don't see that here
```
> _.sortBy(_.keys(Meteor.Collection), function(v) { return v });
[ 'Cursor',
  'ObjectID',
  '_projectionFn',
  '_publishCursor',
  '_rewriteSelector',
  '_selectorId',
  '_transform',
  'collection',
  'fields',
  'limit',
  'matcher',
  'reactive',
  'skip',
  'sorter' ]
> Meteor.isServer
true
```

Comment: `MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db`

Answer (score 0):

I think now you can use this method:

```
MyCollection.rawCollection()
```

https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-rawCollection